# pie chart labels not appearing properly only for certain facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, tidyverse

I am trying to create a pie chart with a number of facets, each with its own labels for percentages. It seems to work for certain datasets, while not for others. Below is a fully reproducible example of a dataset where the **label positions** are appropriate one facet (`cyl: 4`), but not for others (`cyl: 6` and `cyl: 8`). For example, if you look at `cyl: 6`, slice with 57% has been labeled with the label for 43% and vice versa.

Anybody knows what's the origin of this behavior and how can I get rid of it?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

# creating a dataframe
df <- dplyr::group_by(mtcars, .dots = c('cyl', 'am')) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(perc))

# preparing the plot
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes('', counts)) +
  geom_col(
    position = 'fill',
    color = 'black',
    width = 1,
    aes(fill = factor(am))
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller = "label_both") +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = paste0(round(perc), "%"), group = factor(am)),
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    color = 'black',
    size = 5,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-03 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: Not reproducible for me, I get the correct percent labels and positions using your code. Check that `ggplot2` is up to date.

Comment: @Mako212 Sorry, maybe phrasing was inaccurate. The **labels** are correct but the **label positions** are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: As of the latest ggplot2 code base slated for release as ggplot2 2.3.0, this issue seems to be fixed. My old answer is retained below for archival purposes.**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

# creating a dataframe
df <- dplyr::group_by(mtcars, .dots = c('cyl', 'am')) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(perc))

# preparing the plot
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes('', counts)) +
  geom_col(
    position = 'fill',
    color = 'black',
    width = 1,
    aes(fill = factor(am))
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller = "label_both") +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = paste0(round(perc), "%"), group = factor(am)),
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    color = 'black',
    size = 5,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Chicago             
#>  date     2018-05-13
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version    date       source                          
#>  assertthat   0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  backports    1.1.2      2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  base       * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  bindr        0.1.1      2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  bindrcpp   * 0.2        2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  colorspace   1.4-0      2017-12-23 R-Forge (R 3.5.0)               
#>  compiler     3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  curl         3.1        2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  datasets   * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  devtools     1.13.5     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  digest       0.6.15     2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  dplyr      * 0.7.4      2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  evaluate     0.10.1     2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  ggplot2    * 2.2.1.9000 2018-05-12 local                           
#>  glue         1.2.0      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  graphics   * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  grDevices  * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  grid         3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  htmltools    0.3.6      2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  httr         1.3.1      2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  knitr        1.20       2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  labeling     0.3        2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  methods    * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  mime         0.5        2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  pillar       1.2.1      2018-02-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  pkgconfig    2.0.1      2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  R6           2.2.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  Rcpp         0.12.16    2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  rlang        0.2.0.9001 2018-05-10 Github (r-lib/rlang@ccdbd8b)    
#>  rmarkdown    1.9        2018-03-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2      2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  scales       0.5.0.9000 2018-04-10 Github (hadley/scales@d767915)  
#>  stats      * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  stringi      1.1.7      2018-03-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  stringr      1.3.0      2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  tibble       1.4.2      2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  tools        3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  utils      * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  withr        2.1.2      2018-05-10 Github (jimhester/withr@79d7b0d)
#>  xml2         1.2.0      2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  yaml         2.1.18     2018-03-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```

---

**Old answer**

Seems like `geom_col()` in **ggplot2_2.2.1.9000** cares about the order of the data in the data frame. This works:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

# creating a dataframe
df <- dplyr::group_by(mtcars, .dots = c('cyl', 'am')) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(perc = (counts / sum(counts)) * 100) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(cyl, desc(am)) # change in the code is here, I'm sorting by cyl and am, not by perc

# preparing the plot
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes('', counts)) +
  geom_col(
    position = 'fill',
    color = 'black',
    width = 1,
    aes(fill = factor(am))
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller = "label_both") +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = paste0(round(perc), "%"), group = factor(am)),
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    color = 'black',
    size = 5,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2       ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 dplyr_0.7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get when I run your code:

[image]

Check that `ggplot2` is updated.

I'm running `ggplot2_2.2.1`and R Version 3.4.3

Comment: Huh, this is puzzling. I am using R Version 3.4.1 and developmental version `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`

I will try using the version of `ggplot2` you are using to see if this issue still persists.

Comment: Wow, you are right! If I use `ggplot2_2.2.1`, there is no error, but if I use `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`, it gives an incorrect figure. Odd. I will report this on their GitHub page.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil In the development version of ggplot2, `geom_col()` plots the data in the order in the data frame. That's not necessarily wrong, just different from how it was before.